# Execute Jenkins pipeline's specific stage using Stage view or Jenkins CLI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to execute specific pipeline's stage from Stage View or Jenkins CLI?

for example for the following pipeline, is it possible to execute stage("B") only?

```
def start(Map data) {
    node {
       stage("A") {
       }
       stage("B") {
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

Tried the following cli command:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[ip]:[port]/ -auth user:password restart-from-stage -j [JOB_NAME] -s [stage name]
```

however get error:

```
ERROR: Not authorized to restart builds of this job
```

Comment: why would you do that?